# Redux saga is called twice with one dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Im trying to comprehend the art of redux saga, but faced this situation:

I have useEffect hook that works correctly(works one time when changing url params). This hook dispatches action(created by redux-saga-routines) only one time.

```
    const params = useParams().params;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (urlTriggers.some(item => item === params)) {
            dispatch(setItemsCollection({ itemType: params }));
            toggleVisibleMode(true);
        } else {
            toggleVisibleMode(false);
        }
    }, [params]);
```

Saga watcher reacts to the dispatched action

```
export function* setItemsCollectionWatcher() {    
    yield takeEvery(setItemsCollection.TRIGGER, setItemsCollectionWorker);
}
```

And then calls saga worker

```
function* setItemsCollectionWorker(action) {
    const { itemType } = action.payload;
    try {        
        yield put(toggleIsFetching({ isFetching: true }));

        const itemsCollection = yield call(() => {
            return axios.get(`http://localhost:60671/api/items/${itemType}/?page=1&count=2`).then(response => response.data.items);
        });
        yield put(setItemsCollection.success({ itemsCollection }));
        yield put(toggleIsFetching({ isFetching: false }));

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        yield put(setItemsCollection.fulfill());
    }
}
```

This saga listens all saga watchers

```
export default function* saga() {
    yield all([
        setBackgroundWatcher(),
        setItemsCollectionWatcher(),
    ])
}
```

saga running

```
sagaMiddleware.run(saga);
```

```
export const setItemsCollection = createRoutine('showcase/SET_ITEMS_COLLECTION');
export const toggleIsFetching = createRoutine('showcase/TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING');

const showcase = createReducer(
    {
        itemsCollection: [],
        isFetching: false,
    },
    {
        [setItemsCollection.SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
            state.itemsCollection = action.payload.itemsCollection;
        },
        [toggleIsFetching.TRIGGER]: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = action.payload.isFetching;
        },
    }
);
```

But I have 2 axios requests instead of just one.

Comment: are you sure about the useEffect ? place a console.log('test') just before             dispatch(setItemsCollection({ itemType: params }));
 and confirm that console.log will appear once.

Comment: If you don't see two `console.log`'s with the above, do you see the action logged twice in the Redux Devtools?

Comment: @novonimo , console.log appeared only once. 
'if' condition prevents the dispatch from being executed twice.

Comment: @chris , two showcase/SET_ITEMS_COLLECTION/TRIGGER and the same number of showcase/SET_ITEMS_COLLECTION/SUCCES in Redux Devtools :)

Comment: Okay, go another step further,  are you sure the "SET_ITEMS_COLLECTION" action is only used in this saga or you used it on your reducer, other sagas by mistakes?

Comment: @novonima , I use it only in this saga. I presented the sequence of calling the sagas above. There is another saga, but it does not use this action. I added code of reducer, that is bounded with this action, in the body of the question.

Comment: any solution? facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch from the client is type `setItemsCollection` which should be fine (though I generally 'USE_HUGE_OBVIOUS_TEXT_LIKE_THIS'). The response from the promise in your saga is the same: `setItemsCollection` whereas, depending on what you're trying to render, you may want to call your reducer with something entirely different.

At a glance, I'd suggest changing this line to something else (and matching what the reducer is listening for). I wonder if it's causing a crossed wire somewhere.